Compute SHAP Value for a systems of model using shap.DeepExplainer
I have trained a two-stage ML model training for binary classification. In the first stage, I applied an autoencoder model consisting of encoder and decoder. The encoder model has reduced the dimension of the input feature from 1000 to 32. The decoder reconstructs the input by increasing the input feature from 32 to 1000. From the encoder output, I have applied a DNN model to binary classify whether the object is a flower or fruit.
Now I want to calculate the feature importance score of this two-stage model. For this, I have computed the SHAP value on the encoder + DNN model to retrieve the feature importance of the raw variable.
I have checked this question. I have used shap.KernelExplainer to compute the feature importance score which is extremely slow. To get the feature importance score of 300 samples, I had to wait approximately 3 hours.
My code:
class ModelWrapper:
    def __init__(self, first_dnn_model, second_dnn_model):
        self.first_dnn_model = first_dnn_model
        self.second_dnn_model = second_dnn_model

    def predict_proba(self, X):
        
        self.first_dnn_model.eval()
        self.second_dnn_model.eval()
        
        with torch.no_grad(): 
            X_tensor = torch.from_numpy(X)
            X_dnn = self.first_dnn_model(X_tensor)
            return  self.second_dnn_model(X_dnn).numpy()

explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(modelwrapper.predict_proba, X_train[:100]) 
shap_value_for_test = explainer.shap_values(X_test)

The reason is quite clear. shap.KernelExplainer runs on CPU. I can compute shap value using shap.DeepExplainer but can not compute shap value on series of two models.
My Question:

How can I speed up computation time of shap.KernelExplainer ?

How can I compute the feature importance score of a series of two models?
raw variable ==> autoencoder ==> DNN model ==> output


How can I compute the feature importance score of the encoder + DNN model using shap.DeepExplainer?
What else I tried:
1. I have read Matthews & Hartman (2021) and found their GitHub repository and Python port of the package mshap.
Code:
Model Training:
X = r.X
y1 = r.cost_per_month
y2 = r.num_months

cpm_mod = sk.RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 100, max_depth = 10, max_features = 2)
cpm_mod.fit(X, y1) 
nm_mod = sk.RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 100, max_depth = 10, max_features = 2)
nm_mod.fit(X, y2) 
cpm_preds = cpm_mod.predict(X)
nm_preds = nm_mod.predict(X) 
tot_rev = cpm_preds * nm_preds

Model Explanation:
cpm_ex = shap.Explainer(cpm_mod)
cpm_shap = cpm_ex.shap_values(X)
cpm_expected_value = cpm_ex.expected_value

nm_ex = shap.Explainer(nm_mod)
nm_shap = nm_ex.shap_values(X)
nm_expected_value = nm_ex.expected_value

Shap Value Calculation:
## R
final_shap <- mshap(
  shap_1 = py$cpm_shap, 
  shap_2 = py$nm_shap, 
  ex_1 = py$cpm_expected_value, 
  ex_2 = py$nm_expected_value
)

head(final_shap$shap_vals)

Why my case is different from this paper:
I am not doing binary classification by multiplying two models' output. I have used the output of the first model as input to 2nd model.
2. I have also read Chen, Lundberg, Lee (2022) and gone through their repository, DeepShap. But this also does not answer my question.
Code of this paper:
explicand = X_test; reference = X_train
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model, data=reference)
tree_attr = explainer.shap_values(X_test, per_reference=True)
shap.summary_plot(tree_attr.mean(2), features=explicand, show=False,
                  feature_names=explicand.columns, max_display=6)

My Purpose:
My task is to compute the shapely value for features of input data that impact mostly binary classification. Any hint or paper link will be a great help to me.

Is this a duplicate: have you checked the 488 existing posts on "SHAP value", e.g. Top N features that are responsible for the local SHAP value or How to interpret base_value of GBT classifier when using SHAP? which use simpler architectures. If it is a duplicate, please identify the closest existing question.

...based on those existing Q&A, show us your code and results where trying to compute the SHAP values to get the top 5 or top 10 features got stuck.

I have updated my questions and showed my trying and minimal code.

Again, when you search for computing SHAP for multistage or DNN, cite which other people's approaches you tried, show that code and where you got stuck.

To be clear: you need to search for computing SHAP for multistage or DNN on Google, ResearchGate, Kaggle, papers, whatever. Not just here on SO. Those citations exist, you have to find them. Then try to adapt them and post your code attempt on that. You haven't done that. SO rules require that you do.

I have cited all papers that match this question. The code from these papers is also added. I have not found anything on the internet to compute shapely value for two-stage ML  model training (autoencoder + DNN ).

Ok you updated the code after I asked. You haven't cited any papers, that means posting the URLs.

I cited the paper. Yesterday, I cited the paper but later removed it.

Ok you added the citations and an explanation what you tried, good job. I edited the citations to the standard format like "Chen, Lundberg, Lee (2022)". (Note that the citations formatted section at bottom is hidden by SO, so readers can't directly see those URLs unless your question lists what you tried.)
